# Pandas: Conditionally dropping columns based on same values throughout the column in MultiIndex dataframe

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, multi-index

I have a dataframe as below:

```
data = {('5105', 'Open'): [1.99,1.98,1.99,2.05,2.15],
        ('5105', 'Adj Close'): [1.92,1.92,1.96,2.07,2.08],
        ('5229', 'Open'): [0.01]*5,
        ('5229', 'Adj Close'): [0.02]*5,
        ('7076', 'Open'): [1.02,1.01,1.01,1.06,1.06],
        ('7076', 'Adj Close'): [0.90,0.92,0.94,0.94,0.95]}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)

   5105            5229            7076          
   Open Adj Close  Open Adj Close  Open Adj Close
0  1.99      1.92  0.01      0.02  1.02      0.90
1  1.98      1.92  0.01      0.02  1.01      0.92
2  1.99      1.96  0.01      0.02  1.01      0.94
3  2.05      2.07  0.01      0.02  1.06      0.94
4  2.15      2.08  0.01      0.02  1.06      0.95
```

As the dataframe above, we can see that `df['5229']` has both columns `Open` and `Adj Close` having the same values respectively throughout the column. So, I intend to drop it since it will not be useful in my analysis.

I have two queries:

1. How do I drop the column on level 0 (that is the 1st column) if its subcolumns have the same values respectively throughout the column?
2. On the other hand, if there's just one subcolumn that has the same values throughout the column, how can I drop it?

As this is a **conditional-based** dropping, I was wondering if `df.drop` still works in this case?

Based on my 1st and 2nd query, in my case above, since the `Open` and `Adj Close` are having same values throughout the column, I would like to drop it entirely.

The expected output is:

```
   5105            7076          
   Open Adj Close  Open Adj Close
0  1.99      1.92  1.02      0.90
1  1.98      1.92  1.01      0.92
2  1.99      1.96  1.01      0.94
3  2.05      2.07  1.06      0.94
4  2.15      2.08  1.06      0.95
```

### Edit

Really thank you for those answering the question. Just to be more concise, I was trying to drop the columns from the dataframe consisting of more than 200 columns **given the condition** if all the values in that particular column are the same.

Comment: what is your expected output ?

Comment: Thanks for reminding me, I have updated my post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can try this:

```py
for a, b in df.columns:
    if df[a][b].duplicated(keep=False).sum() == df[a][b].size:
        df.drop((a, b), axis=1, inplace=True)
```

Result:

```
   5105            7076          
   Open Adj Close  Open Adj Close
0  1.99      1.92  1.02      0.90
1  1.98      1.92  1.01      0.92
2  1.99      1.96  1.01      0.94
3  2.05      2.07  1.06      0.94
4  2.15      2.08  1.06      0.95
```

Comment: Not the fanciest solution, probably there is a more optimized approach, but for a small dataset should be fine!

Comment: This is a good solution. FYI, instead of double brackets, you could use `df[a,b]`.

Answer (score 1):

Try with `nunique`

```
df = df.loc[:,~(df.nunique()==1).values]
Out[125]: 
   5105            7076          
   Open Adj Close  Open Adj Close
0  1.99      1.92  1.02      0.90
1  1.98      1.92  1.01      0.92
2  1.99      1.96  1.01      0.94
3  2.05      2.07  1.06      0.94
4  2.15      2.08  1.06      0.95
```

Comment: Thank you so much for the answer! This is another way I can look into too :D

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
df.drop('5229',level=0,axis=1)
```

Output:

```
   5105            7076          
   Open Adj Close  Open Adj Close
0  1.99      1.92  1.02      0.90
1  1.98      1.92  1.01      0.92
2  1.99      1.96  1.01      0.94
3  2.05      2.07  1.06      0.94
4  2.15      2.08  1.06      0.95
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I need to do it based on conditions according to my two queries. My real dataset has 200 columns and more than one column having same values throughout the column

Answer (score 0):

We could use `unstack` + `groupby` + `nunique` to get the number of unique values in each column. Then select only the columns with more than 1 value by the `loc`:

```
out = df[df.unstack().groupby(level=[0,1]).nunique().loc[lambda x: x!=1].index]
```

Output:

```
       5105            7076      
  Adj Close  Open Adj Close  Open
0      1.92  1.99      0.90  1.02
1      1.92  1.98      0.92  1.01
2      1.96  1.99      0.94  1.01
3      2.07  2.05      0.94  1.06
4      2.08  2.15      0.95  1.06
```

Comment: Hi @enke, really appreciate your effort to answer my questions :-D I was actually wondering if it works on a given condition? For example, I was manually dropping columns with the same values throughout the column, but I have more than 200 columns to do so.

Comment: It's ok, thank you so much for the answer :D This looks very pythonic to me! I've never thought about doing it this way. For my current level, I will try with @Caio Lopes' answer first. Thanks again